# How do you update an Angular scope parameter with results from Google Maps Places API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I want to allow a user to search for a location with the Google Places API, and then when they click on a given location, to update the value of a parameter on the scope.

Hopefully some visuals will help:

[image: Locations updating as user types]

So the Google part works correctly. However, when the user clicks on "New South Wales", this is the following result of evaluating `{{ table.newItem }}`:

[image: Value of {{table.newItem }}]

As you can see, the value on my scope has not updated due to the user's click event.

I'm not familiar with how to use `$watch()` or `$apply()`. Could any of those be useful here?

Also, where should I be placing this code? Right now it is in a link function, so that I can target the input box on a click event. Should it go somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the logic where you set the scope variable in `$scope.$apply`.

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
  // modify scope here
});
```

The reason is that Angular has an event loop known as the digest cycle. It's always running. During a digest cycle Angular will process its data model, detect any changes, and then update the UI to reflect the updated data model. This all works great when the data model is updated at the proper moment during the digest cycle.

When you use external libraries you'll often end up tying code to triggers that happen outside of Angular's digest cycle. For example, even a simple `setTimeout` would fire outside of a digest cycle because it would be fired off by the JavaScript engine itself in a later iteration of the JavaScript event loop.

When this happens, the data model does change as you expect it to, but the UI update portion of the digest cycle doesn't run because Angular has not detected the change yet. If you perform another operation (even an unrelated one) to modify scope inside a proper digest cycle, then suddenly you'd see the UI update to reflect those changes plus the changes you made outside of a digest cycle.

You would have to wrap the contents of the timeout in `$scope.$apply` to ensure that Angular is aware of the changes and can update any UI components appropriately.

```
// Won't update any UI bound to "message" properly
// until something else triggers a UI update in a later digest cycle.
setTimeout(function () {
  $scope.message = "hi";
}, 0);

// Will update the UI immediately as expected because you're manually
// telling Angular to run the logic during a digest cycle.
setTimeout(function () {
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.message = "hi";
  });
});
```

This is also the reason angular provides a `$timeout` service of its own. It's literally just an angular service that wraps `setTimeout` and does the `$scope.$apply` for you behind the scenes.

Any logic inside the callback passed to `$scope.$apply` will be held and executed during a digest cycle at the proper moment, allowing Angular to update the UI normally with up to date data from the data model.

I haven't worked with the Google Maps API but I'm pretty certain you're probably hooking into a callback or event that is fired/triggered by the Google Maps API. If that's the case, wrap the logic in that handler in `$scope.$apply` and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That worked, although I'm not sure I am doing it in the right place. Currently doing it in a link function, but hey, it works! Thanks again.

Comment: It's very common to do it inside a link function. If you're wrapping a non-angular control or service in a custom directive, then you'll be configuring that control/service inside the link function, including setting up event handlers. So yeah, inside those handlers you'd need to call `$scope.$apply` :)

Comment: I had a similar issue trying to update a variable in the scope via a google map click event. `$watch` was not picking up on the change. Using `$scope.$apply` within the click event callback solved the problem. Thanks!